# Is there a way to don't exit on ncurses initscr error?

Tags: ncurses

Ncurses initscr() on errors just exits the program.

Is there a way to trap the error?

I red all the manual on ncurses, but all say that iniscr just don't give possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`newterm`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html) instead of `initscr` if you are concerned about error handling.  On error, `newterm` returns a null pointer (and does not exit).